# Putnam and Skolem Paradox

Tags: logic, metaphysics

Why, according to Putnam in "Models and Reality", is moderate realism more affected by the so-called Löwenheim-Skolem Paradox than extreme realism?

I understand the gist of Putnam's grip with the Skolem Paradox. But may I know why Putnam thinks that it affects moderate realism more than extreme realism (he classifies Platonism and Verificationism under this label)

Comment: See page 466: [Platonist] will say, "Nonsense! All the 'paradox' shows is that our understanding of 'The real numbers are nondenumerable' consists in our knowing
what it is for this to be proved, and not in our 'grasp' of a 'model'."

Comment: The Platonist postulates an "intuition" about real facts (mathematical abstract objects) that in some sense transcends linguistic capabilities, while a "moderate" realist is more subject to the limits of language.

Comment: See page 464: "the moderate realist position which seeks to preserve the
centrality of the classical notions of truth and reference without postulating
nonnatural mental powers."